# EventWaitHandleAccessRule is not exist in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to create `EventWaitHandle` like in the post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle.openexisting?view=dotnet-uwp-10.0

I connected the library `System.Security.AccessControl;` but I don't see the classes I need:

```
EventWaitHandleAccessRule
EventWaitHandleSecurity
```

Also `EventWaitHandle` has no fifth parameter: `EventWaitHandleSecurity`

Comment: `EventWaitHandleAccessRule` and `EventWaitHandleSecurity` are not available in UWP or .NET Standard.

Comment: In the post:
Applies to
.NET Core
3.0 Preview 6 2.2 2.1 2.0 1.1 1.0
.NET Framework
4.8 4.7.2 4.7.1 4.7 4.6.2 4.6.1 4.6 4.5.2 4.5.1 4.5 4.0 3.5 3.0 2.0
.NET Standard
2.1 Preview 2.0 1.6 1.4 1.3 1.2 1.1 1.0
UWP
10.0
Xamarin.Android
7.1
Xamarin.iOS
10.8
Xamarin.Mac
3.0
I resolved my problem with System.Security.AccessControl; but EventWaitHandle has no fifth parameter: EventWaitHandleSecurity

How i can resolve my problem?

Comment: @Mind mm8 has replied to you. These two class are not supported in UWP. See [.NET API Browser for EventWaitHandleAccessRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=EventWaitHandleAccessRule&view=dotnet-uwp-10.0) and [.NET API Browser for EventWaitHandleSecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=EventWaitHandleSecurity&view=dotnet-uwp-10.0).